# Perfomance tweak for this query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, performance-testing, database-performance

I am writting the following query,

[Execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJFZY7xjl)

Its takes 30 seconds to load just 80 rows.

Is there anything we can do to reduce the time of running this query?

```
select 
   CO.ContributorsName [ContributorsName]
 , D.DocumentLastPublished DocumentLastPublished
 , CO.ContributorsImage [AuthorImage]
 , T.NodeAliasPath
 , D.DocumentID
 , BD.*
from CMS_Tree T
  inner join Cms_Class CC 
    on T.NodeClassID = CC.ClassID
   and CC.ClassName = 'wv.blogdata'
  inner join Cms_Document D 
    on T.NodeID = D.DocumentNodeID
  inner join WV_BlogData BD 
    on D.DocumentForeignKeyValue = BD.BlogDataID
   and COALESCE(BD.IsDeleted, 0) = 0
  inner join WV_Contributors CO 
    on BD.AuthorID = CO.ContributorsID
where (
  'ALL' = 'ALL'
  or category = 'All'
  )
 and DocumentCulture = 'en-US'
```

[image: Execution plan]

Comment: What can you talk about the column datatypes and indexes in place?

Comment: Execution plan?

Comment: 80 rows total, together in all tables?

Comment: It's usually better to use AND/OR instead of case/coalesce in conditions. E.g. `COALESCE(BD.IsDeleted,0) = 0` can be written as `(BD.IsDeleted = 0 or BD.IsDeleted is null)`.

Comment: I have attached the execution plan

Comment: What is the purpose of 'ALL' = 'ALL'?

Comment: @DanBracuk, that part will probably be optimized away.

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/).

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJFZY7xjl

Comment: Please find the execution plan

Comment: I would expect outdated statistics or something like that. Without actual execution plan it is hard to say. If there is one row estimated in the estimated plan and 100000 rows in the actual plan (may happen easily), the performace would be suboptimal. You also want to have indexes on all columns You use for filtering to have relevant statistics.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use * for all tables.Only specify column names what columns you need.Check your WHERE Clause also.

Comment: How much does this advice improve performance?  It does not seem particularly useful to me.

Comment: Where does the person select *?

Comment: @DanBracuk `,BD.* FROM `

Comment: hmm..bd.* is cousing issues, but not sure where inside bd.* there its causing issues

Comment: i undo accepeted this answer, if you have any better answers i will wait

Comment: @GordonLinoff how come that's not useful? The table name is wv_BlogData. I'm assuming it has ntext fields.

Comment: This is not useful because replacing `*` with the columns in the tables is going to have zero effect on the query.  Perhaps removing very big columns *could* affect performance, but that is rather unrelated to how the columns are included in the query.

Comment: Having columns You do not need may affect query significantly, as some indexes may become not covering.

Comment: If some of the columns are located in off table storage, using `select *` could have a massive detrimental impact to the query performance.  This is sound advice IMO.

Answer (score 0):

**Covering indexes**

(Looking at your execution plan, it looks like you've already got the appropriate covering indexes, but this is good general advice, and still worth a try)

If this is a frequently used query, make sure you've got the appropriate covering indexes on the tables involved.  See [this MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345417(v=sql.105).aspx) page for how to identify potential missing indexes.  Note that adding indexes will improve query performance, at the cost of degrading your insert performance.  You will also need to make sure you've got the appropriate maintenance plans in place to ensure your indexes don't get fragmented or unbalanced.

**Query changes**

I'd also recommend trying some changes to your query and comparing the execution plans.

It's difficult to make any meaningful suggestions without looking at your database and being able to try a few things.

From a cursory look at your query, the most obvious thing I can see is that you're performing an inner join on Cms_Class, but not selecting any of the data from it, or even joining it to other tables (apart from CMS_Tree).  I'd suggest removing this join and using an exists statement instead, like so:

```sql
select 
   CO.ContributorsName [ContributorsName]
 , D.DocumentLastPublished DocumentLastPublished
 , CO.ContributorsImage [AuthorImage]
 , T.NodeAliasPath
 , D.DocumentID
 , BD.*
from CMS_Tree T
  inner join Cms_Document D 
    on T.NodeID = D.DocumentNodeID
  inner join WV_BlogData BD 
    on D.DocumentForeignKeyValue = BD.BlogDataID
   and COALESCE(BD.IsDeleted, 0) = 0
  inner join WV_Contributors CO 
    on BD.AuthorID = CO.ContributorsID
where (
  'ALL' = 'ALL'
  or category = 'All'
)
and DocumentCulture = 'en-US'
and exists
(
  select null
  from Cms_Class CC 
  where T.NodeClassID = CC.ClassID
  and CC.ClassName = 'wv.blogdata'
)
```

Give it a try, look at the execution plans, and see if it makes a difference for you.

If you create new covering indexes, re-run your queries and look at the execution plans again, because the most efficient query with missing indexes might not be the most efficient query once you've added indexes.

**Document caching (SQL isn't always the best solution for accessing data)**

Assuming you've done both of these, and the query performance is still too poor, you may want to ask yourself if you really need to query live data.  Looking at your query, it looks like you're querying data from a CMS.  The data in a CMS is only going to change when a content author actually makes a change.  Most of the time, the data will stay the same from request to request.  This means that doing a direct query from SQL every time you want to access content might be overkill for your needs.

A good use-case example is to look at how Umbraco CMS accesses its data.  It keeps an XML document cache of all of the published documents on a given site.  When a content author publishes changes, it then updates the XML document cache.

Accessing the cache is much more efficient than talking to SQL directly, and they even warn users not to use their SQL API for serving up CMS content, because it is too slow.